# Eclipse: find workspace references -> one liners?

Tags: eclipse

When i search for references in the workspace (shift+ctrl+G) in Eclipse im not so interested in seeing all the file trees in the results. I need to expand and click a lot to find the references i want. I would also like the code-line  directly to see what context the code is used in.

I would like a feature that is more closely to what i can do in visual studio. If the reference searched for is "myFunc" and 2 references exist i just want two lines in the results.

Example:

```
c:/data/foo.java:      myFunc (someButton, 45);
c:/gfx/imports.java:   return myFunc (importButton, 25);
```

Double-click on a line should bring me to the location in the code. Is there something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the Search view click on the small triangle at the top right of the view to bring up the View Menu. Select 'Show as List' rather than 'Show as Tree'.

Comment: Thanks, but some problems with this:
1. Lists only the methods using the searched item (if several it just says "4 matches" it doesnt show all the actual matches)
2. Doesnt show the code line so no context.

Comment: This is as close as you will get from standard Eclipse